# How a WiFi mesh system forces a client to connect to the closest node?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am reading in a lot of WiFi mesh products that the client is connected to the closest node in the mesh system thus having better speeds, more reliable connection etc. This sounds great but can someone please explain how a mesh system forces the client to connect to the closest node?

My understanding on WiFi access points and extenders/repeaters downside is that the client is connected to an AP and if you move around the client will continue to connect to the same AP (even if another one is closer) until the AP's signal is completely lost. Then it will try to find another AP with strong signal and connect to that. The issue is that you can be connected to an AP further away, with much lower dBm, and get slower speeds and signal, even if you are sitting next to another one with much better signal. My understanding is that the AP cannot force the client to connect to another AP or an AP cannot force the client to connect to it. It is the client's decision all the time.

So, how a WiFi mesh network solves this problem? Why when I move around and get closer to a mesh node the client will decide to connect to that node, even if the signal from a further away node is still available and the client is connected to it?

Answer (score 0):

The various Mesh variants are mainly based on the implementation of already existing wireless standards, namely 802.11k, 802.11r and 802.11v.

If a wireless client device doesn't support any of these standards, then it is apparently indeed possible to force the device to disconnect, in the hope that it will then re-connect to another AP with a better signal.

The following link leads to a webpage of networking equipment maker "AVM" and provides some good details about this, [What is Mesh Wi-Fi steering and how does it work?](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/3515_What-is-Mesh-Wi-Fi-steering-and-how-does-it-work/).

Comment: Please [edit] and include the relevent part of the link in the answer.